# "repo sync" failed with "bad command: git-upload-pack '...' "

Tags: gitolite, repo

In the following log, the URL repos/repoman@svr:repos/apps/init is wrong.

The right URL should be repoman@svr:repos/apps/init.

Gitolite is running on the server, svr.

Please indicate what should be modified to make repo sync work properly.

Thanks!

```
me@ubuntu1204x64:/home/me/work$ repo init -u repoman@svr:repos/manifests -m model_r1.xml
Get repoman@svr:repos/manifests
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
From 172.16.100.235:/mdm9640_le/manifests
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master`

me@ubuntu1204x64:/home/me/work$ repo sync
Fetching project apps/init
bad command: git-upload-pack repos/repoman@svr:repos/apps/init
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

me@ubuntu1204x64:/home/me/work$ cat .repo/manifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
   <remote fetch="repoman@svr:repos" name="origin"/>
   <default remote="origin" revision="model_r1"/>
   <project path="apps/init" name="apps/init" revision="refs/heads/model_r1" />
</manifest>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://bbs.scmlife.com/thread-29024-1-1.html,

```
<remote fetch="./" name="origin"/>
```

works well.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time while trying it myself. For people looking for answer in the future (like myself), the corrct way to use gitolite repo which is not in subdirectory of init repo you can just use

```
<remote fetch="git+ssh://user@server/" name="gitolite" />
```